# What javascript library for this interactive function explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, interactive

I want to create an interactive web page were users can see how the plot of a particular multi-parameter function is affected as one varies its various parameters.

The function I want to illustrate is pretty hairy, but for the sake of this question, let's say it is f(t) = A sin(ω t + ϕ).  In this case the webpage would have sliders or dials that would let the user interactively dial values for A, ω, and ϕ.  The plot of the function would change simultaneously, reflecting the instantaneous values of the three parameters.

<sub>(I looked into d3.js for this, but I'm not convinced it's the right tool for the job (amazing as it is otherwise), primarily because d3.js seems to be optimized for working with pre-existing data, whereas, for the application I have in mind, there is not data, really.  I realize that one can create "synthetic data" from the function, but this smacks of "force-fitting the problem into the tool".  IOW, my question is not whether d3.js one *could* implement such a webapp with d3.js, but rather whether it is the best tool for the job.)</sub>

As I look further into this problem I find a whole slew of JS libraries for graphics, but none of the ones I found seemed to focus on plotting mathematical expressions.  I could use some guidance as to which of all the JS graphics libraries out there would be best for the task I described above.  In particular, it must provide good support for plotting (mathematical) functions (like sqrt, sine, log, etc.), and good support for the type of interactive re-plotting I described.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [Pre3D](http://deanm.github.io/pre3d/) as a solid starting point.

Take a look at [example](http://www.graphycalc.com/) of using Pre3D. With several sliders that change parameters of choice, you can fairly easy achieve nice interactivity, replotting, etc. There is also a small parser within Pre3D that you can utilize, too.